# Is Int an Ordered type in Scala?

Tags: scala

Well, it doesn't seem to be. The following code:

```
  def inBounds[T <: Ordered[T]](lowerBound: T, value: T, upperBound: T): Boolean =
    lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound
```

Gives me an error at compilation time:

```
Error:(55, 13) inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method inBounds's 
type parameter bounds [T <: Ordered[T]]
```

But... `Int` has to be "`Ordered`" somehow. Am I missing some `import` for some implicits?

Comment: Int is a `Numeric` which has `Ordering`. 

```
def inBounds[T <: Ordering](lowerBound: T, value: T, upperBound: T): Boolean =
    lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Int is a `Numeric` which has `Ordering`. As all other primitive JVM types, it doesn't extend anything else. This is worth reading on.

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

def inBounds[T : Ordering](
  lowerBound: T,
  value: T,
  upperBound: T
): Boolean = {
    lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound
}
```

It's worth noting that most of the time you will deal with Scala's implicit flavour of ordering, instead of `Ordered`, which only really exists for legacy reasons.(e.g Java interop).

If you dive in the source code [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/math/Ordered.scala#L1) you will notice it actually extends `java.lang.Comparable[T]`, so that's why there's both `Ordering` and `Ordered`.

Comment: @userunknown Updated, you need one more import.

Comment: Is `Int` primitive? I would have thought `int` was the primitive type.

Comment: so there was an import missing, on top of changing `Ordered` to `Ordering`. I could smell that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use <% instead of <:?

```
scala> def inBounds[T <% Ordered[T]](lowerBound: T, value: T, upperBound: T): Boolean =
     |     lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound
inBounds: [T](lowerBound: T, value: T, upperBound: T)(implicit evidence$1: T => Ordered[T])Boolean

scala> inBounds (3, 4, 5)
res32: Boolean = true
```

REPL and Tzach Zohar are pointing out:

```
def inBounds[T](lowerBound: T, 
  value: T, 
  upperBound: T)(implicit ev$1: T => Ordered[T]): Boolean =
    lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound
```

which is then no longer deprecated.

Comment: Note that view bounds are deprecated, so this should be "de-sugared" into `def inBounds[T](lowerBound: T, value: T, upperBound: T)(implicit ev$1: T => Ordered[T]): Boolean`.

Comment: @TzachZohar: I don't get a warning in the REPL, is that to be expected? Scala 2.11.6 version.

Comment: Version 2.11.0-RC1 should already include this warning (I do see it in IDE), see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629. Not sure why not visible in REPL